# I can't find my .minecraft folder (windows 10 minecraft edition)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows

I have tried `%appdata%\.minecraft` but it isn't there! Where can I find my save files?

Comment: Could you please reword your question to be a bit more less childish?

Comment: @aytimothy If you think a post can be improved, you're welcome to edit it.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I thought that fell under changing the intent and not letting the user self-improve?

Comment: @aytimothy Were you planning on changing the intent? Changing the question to something else? If the same information is being conveyed and the same question is being asked, edits that make a post easier to read are encouraged. There's no such thing as "letting the user self-improve" by not editing their post; leading by example is more effective.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the Java Edition saves to `%appdata%\.minecraft`.

However, Windows Store Applications are sandboxed and have their own individual save spots that are sandboxed from the rest of the system that are stored in `%localappdata%\Packages`.

You can find Minecraft Bedrock Edition's (`Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe`) save data by adding its package name onto the root folder I mentioned above... So basically:

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang
```

... which basically translates to (usually, unless you've moved your `%userprofile%`; home folder):

```
C:\Users\[Your Username]\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang
```